# Excel converts document exported from google keyword tool numbers into dates

Tags: excel, formatting

When I import document from google keyword tool some curency values are converted to date for example 5.21 is converted to May 21. However there are some in the same column that are not conveted. What should I do that my document would not be disorted ? Tried to remove text proofing when typing, however I have document prewriten by google so it dosen't help.

Answer (score 0):

Your regional settings seem to have the dot in the date format, with an order of MDY, so Excel will interpret a number like 5.21 as a date, but a number like 5.66 will remain a number.

Try exporting the Google output to a text file. Then open the text file with Excel via the File > Open menu. This will bring up the text import wizard.  In Step 3 of the wizard you can select each column of data and specify what data type it contains, i.e. to tell Excel what each column contains.

You regional settings may also be set to have a comma as the decimal separator. In this case, Excel will not recognize 5.21 as a number at all. You can

- change the Google output to produce numbers like 5,21 or
- temporarily change your regional settings to use the format Google serves you
- mark the column as text and import it as text, then use find and replace on that column to replace the decimal character with the one your system uses.